# jQuery capture href (heatmap/usability)

Tags: jquery, ajax, usability, href, heatmap

I want to create a heatmap from mousedown event, but before this i need to capture the A element on a website. Does anyone know how i could achieve this?

in short:
if i click a link it should be doing the following:

1. capture the link.
2. wait for $.POST/AJAX request.
3. go to the link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('a').click(function(){
    $.ajax({
        url: '/analytics',
        type: 'post',
        data: {url: $(this).attr('href')},
        async: false
    });
}
```

Comment: Thank you, sometimes i see don't see the trees in the forest anymore. :-D